# Intellij hint for output type of a scala method

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have written a method in scala program in Intellij like this:

```
def myMethod(c: Option[C]) = {
    val x = ...
    val y = ...
    c.filter(...)
     .map(_ => {
          (x,y) match {
             case (a,b) => "val1"
             case (c,d) => "val2"
             case (_, _) => "val3"
          }
       })
}
```

Intellij hints that output type of this method is Option[String]. But as I have used filter method , which may return None, so is not this hint wrong?

Comment: Your question sounds contradictory to me. The IDE says the method returns an Option. Your `filter`, as you correctly point out, returns an Option. Yet you say the IDE is wrong for agreeing with you? I don't follow.

Comment: But if filter returns None, map wont even be applied. So shouldn't return type be something which is common ancestor to None and Option[String].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object None` extends `Option[Nothing]`.

`Nothing` is a "bottom type", i.e. it inherits from everything.

`Option` is covariant on its type parameter.

That means that `None` is a descendant from `Option[X]` for any and every possible `X`.

Thus the LUB (Least Upper Bound) between `None` and `Option[String]` is `Option[String]`.